# Dynamic change grouped_collection_select in edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

The app has a categories, categories have subcategory and brands. When user сhoose category, load categorie brands and subcategory. In create form all worck good.

## _form.html.slimm

```
= form_for @advert do |f|
  - @advert.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
    div class='msg'
      = msg

  div class='form-group'
    = f.label :category
    = f.collection_select :category_id, Category.order(:id), :id, :title, { prompt: t("forms.selecte.choose-category")}

  div class='form-group'
    = f.label :subcategory
    = f.grouped_collection_select :subcategory_id, Category.order(:id), :subcategories, :title, :id, :title,{ prompt:  t("forms.selecte.choose-subcategory")}

  div class='form-group'
    = f.label :brand
    = f.grouped_collection_select :brand_id, Category.order(:id), :brands, :title, :id, :title,{ prompt:  t("forms.selecte.choose-brand")}

  div class='form-group'
    = f.label :title
    = f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control'

  div class='form-group'
    = f.label :content
    = f.text_area :content, size: '60x12', class: 'form-control'

  = f.submit t('forms.buttons.submit')
```

## advert.coffee

```
ready = ->
  jQuery ->
    $('#advert_subcategory_id').parent().hide()
    $('#advert_brand_id').parent().hide()
    subcategories = $('#advert_subcategory_id').html()
    brands = $('#advert_brand_id').html()
    $('#advert_category_id').change ->
      category = $('#advert_category_id :selected').text()
      escaped_category = category.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
      options_subcategories = $(subcategories).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_category}']").html()
      options_brand = $(brands).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_category}']").html()
      if options_subcategories
        $('#advert_subcategory_id').html(options_subcategories)
        $('#advert_subcategory_id').parent().show()
      else
        $('#advert_subcategory_id').empty()
        $('#advert_subcategory_id').parent().hide()
      if options_brand
        $('#advert_brand_id').html(options_brand)
        $('#advert_brand_id').parent().show()
      else
        $('#advert_brand_id').empty()
        $('#advert_brand_id').parent().hide()
```

But in edit form the code is not working as it should. Subcategory and brand not load. To change them user must change category.When loading edit form must shows the already selected subcategories and brands. How to fix it?

**Solution:**

```
 $(window).load ->
      category = $('#advert_category_id :selected').text()
      escaped_category = category.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
      options_subcategories = $(subcategories).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_category}']").html()
      options_brand = $(brands).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_category}']").html()
      if options_subcategories
        $('#advert_subcategory_id').html(options_subcategories)
        $('#advert_subcategory_id').parent().show()
      else
        $('#advert_subcategory_id').empty()
        $('#advert_subcategory_id').parent().hide()
      if options_brand
        $('#advert_brand_id').html(options_brand)
        $('#advert_brand_id').parent().show()
      else
        $('#advert_brand_id').empty()
        $('#advert_brand_id').parent().hide()
```

Code duplicated but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution to your problem is in http://andrewradev.com/2011/05/25/grouped-select-helper-methods-in-rails/
Hope it will be helpful for you to solve your problem